# Centralize multiple event subscriptions

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Iv'e just introduced Events and Delegates at work and one of the core questions's was. 
"How would you centralize the event subscriptions?"

Over the last 3-4 days iv'e been working on events and delegates so we can decouple and avoid dependencies.

Business Layer:

```
 //Code omitted for readability
 Public Class CustomerRepository
 { 
    //Delagte/Event here

    //Some method that updates the Customer
    public void Update()
    {
      //Update Magic

      //Fire if subscribed
      OnUpdateCustomer();
    }
 }

 //Methods that will fire when invoked
 Public Class ChangLog
 {

    //Some method that fires when subscribed
    public void OnUpdateCustomer()
    {
      //Some Magic
    }
 }
 Public Class RollbackLog
 {
    //Method that fires when subscribed
    public void OnUpdateCustomer()
    {
      //Some Magic
    }
  }
```

So now the question was raised that if more functionality is added the UI developer needs to subscribe to the events 
and remember where and who requires each event method.
UI Layer:

Code varies whether its Webforms or MVC

```
public void btnClick_OnClick()
{
     CustomerRepository repo = new CustomerRepository();

     ChangeLog changeLog = new ChangeLog();
     repo.CustomerUpdated += changeLog.OnCustomerUpdated;

     RollbackLog rollbackLog = new RollbackLog();
     repo.CustomerUpdated += rollbackLog.OnCustomerUpdated;

     repo.Update();
     //So if more functionality is added then it can get quite cumbersome for the UI developer
}
```

So the question is, what is the best approach to avoid UI from creating subscriptions but still enable the CustomerRepo to be decoupled?
Is their any difintive pattern to group multiple subscriptions?

I hope this make sense. Any help/advice will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Tez Wingfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your CustomRepository decoupled from your ChangeLog and RollbackLog classes then you should look into the Event Aggregator pattern. One example of such pattern is the [EventAggregator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) class in the Prism library.

(Note that you don't need to use the whole Prism way of things in order to use the EventAggregator class.)

Comment: Thanks for the link...That's exactly what I'm looking for but it appears that it's outdated and not really used. I don't want to be going backwards in methodology. Any other ideas? Also I don't want to hack together a solution, I was hoping there was a pattern to follow.

Comment: Ignore that last comment. After further research it seems that it's still widely used. Pluralsight videos and recent articles. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

My consult answer is: It depends.

Your example has one big question:

1) It allows users to build CustomerRepository without ChangeLog and RollbackLog. Do you want that?

If you don't want that and you would like to decouple ChangeLog and RollbackLog from CustomerRepository then one valid approach is using [DI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Usually this is implemented by bringing all the dependencies to constructor. So your CustomerRepository constructor would look like this:

```
public CustomerRepository(IChangeLog changeLog, IRollbackLog rollbackLog)
{
   this.changeLog = changelog;
   this.rollbackLog = rollbackLog;
}
```

and method would be something like this:

```
public void Update()
{
     //Update Magic
     try 
     {
        changeLog.LogUpdateCustomer();
     } 
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         rollbackLog.Rollback();
     }    
}
```

Now if you dont want to use rollback or changelog, just create a class called "SkipChangeLog" which derives from IChangeLog and all the methods are empty.

Comment: Maybe I was a little vague in my question. Ideally I'd like to stick to the event pattern. Yes, decoupling still needs to be a viable option as this can grow considerably large. I need a way to centralize subscriptions and maybe abstract that away from the UI developer. Your answer seems to adhere to the ISP pattern. Never the less good answer.